# Не удается вывести список Listview с помощью БД Realm

Tags: android, listview, realm, android-menu

Имеется поле для ввода текста, введенный текст с которого по кнопке передается в Listview. Итемы ListView можно редактировать, обновлять и удалять.

Главная активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RealmAdapter.OnClickListener {

private static final int INTENT_REQUEST = 123;

public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String TITLE = "title";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String IS_EDIT = "isEdit";

@BindView(R.id.listView)
ListView recyclerView;

private RealmAdapter realmAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    setupAdapter();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addItem:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, AddItemActivity.class), INTENT_REQUEST);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupAdapter() {

    realmAdapter = new RealmAdapter(new RealmController().getInfo());
    realmAdapter.setOnClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(realmAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    setupAdapter();
}

@Override
public void onEditButtonCLick(int id, String title) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddItemActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(IS_EDIT, true);
    intent.putExtra(ID, id);
    intent.putExtra(TITLE, title);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

```
public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.title)
EditText title;

private boolean isEditMode = false;
private int id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        isEditMode = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(IS_EDIT);
        title.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(TITLE));

        id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ID);
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.addButton)
public void onAddClick() {
    if(!isEditMode)
        new RealmController().addInfo(title.getText().toString());
    else
        new RealmController().updateInfo(id, title.getText().toString());
    finish();
}
```

}

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // The default Realm file is "default.realm" in Context.getFilesDir();

    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

}

Адаптер

```
public class RealmAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<RealmModel> {

private OnClickListener onClickListener;

public RealmAdapter(RealmResults<RealmModel> realmResults) {
    super(realmResults);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_realm, parent, false);
    RealmViewHolder viewHolder = new RealmViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


    final RealmModel model = getRealmResults().get(position);
    viewHolder.title.setText(model.getTitle());

    viewHolder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new RealmController().removeItemById(getRealmResults().get(position).getId());
        }
    });
    viewHolder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickListener.onEditButtonCLick(model.getId(), model.getTitle());
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public RealmResults<RealmModel> getRealmResults() {
    return null;
}

public class RealmViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.title)
    TextView title;



    @BindView(R.id.editButton)
    ImageView editButton;

    @BindView(R.id.removeButton)
    ImageView removeButton;

    public RealmViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
}

public interface OnClickListener {
    void onEditButtonCLick(int id, String title);
}
}
```

Контроллер с методами по добавлению, редактированию и удалениб

```
public class RealmController {


private Realm realm;

/*public RealmController(Context context) {
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
    realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}*/

public void addInfo(String title) {

    realm.beginTransaction();

    RealmModel realmObject = realm.createObject(RealmModel.class);
    int id = getNextKey();
    realmObject.setId(id);
    realmObject.setTitle(title);


    realm.commitTransaction();
}

public RealmResults<RealmModel> getInfo() {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    return realm.where(RealmModel.class).findAll();
}

public void updateInfo(int id, String title) {
    realm.beginTransaction();

    RealmModel realmObject = realm.where(RealmModel.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    realmObject.setTitle(title);


    realm.commitTransaction();
}

public void removeItemById(int id) {
    realm.beginTransaction();

    RealmResults<RealmModel> rows = realm.where(RealmModel.class).equalTo("id", id).findAll();
    rows.clear();

    realm.commitTransaction();
}

private int getNextKey() {
    return realm.where(RealmModel.class).max("id").intValue() + 1;
}
}
```

Модель данных

```
public class RealmModel extends RealmObject {

private int id;
private String title;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

}
```

Выдает ошибку в логе

```
09-24 13:42:22.736 25456-25456/com.example.user.testrealm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.testrealm, PID: 25456
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object io.realm.RealmResults.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.user.testrealm.RealmAdapter.getView(RealmAdapter.java:35)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2362)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
```

Comment: если у вас в адаптере метод getRealmResults() возвращает null "прямым текстом", что еще вы планируете получить, кроме NPE?

Comment: до обновления библиотеки realm вместо return null было return realmResults, которое было переменной самой библиотеки. После обновления realm стал ругаться на эту переменную - Cannot resolve symbol 'realmResults'. Что там должно быть?